# would lighter more reflective paint on roof and exterior walls on a building make it cooler?

Tags: civil-engineering

I'm doing a report on how a house can consume less electricity. one of this is to cut power consumption on the air-conditioning. would lighter coloured paint work?, what are some other ways that natural cooling can occurred

Comment: Would that also increase the heating needed in winter?

Comment: Use trees - leaves in summer and no leaves in winter - natures automatic shading system no electricity or gas required. Do a search on passive solar gain or design.

Comment: Flat or pitched ? Dirt on a painted surface is very large factor according to actual measurements made on oil storage tanks ( sides ). So for a flat roof that collects dirt , color may not make much difference.

Comment: A recent (2021.10.31) [news story](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2021-10-30/climate-change-now-australia-glasgow-cop26/100538662) that might be of interest. A white roof will help, but insulation & double glazing also increase the affect.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, so much so that in the USA it is rewarded in LEED, Green system, scores and codified into building code.

All office building rooftops must be in white color and other roofing systems are encouraged to be in light colors and use heat reflecting material.

This is the city of Los Angeles cool roof link.[cool roof](https://www.ladbs.org/docs/default-source/publications/ordinances/cool-roof-fact-sheet-and-faq.pdf?sfvrsn=10)

[https://www.asla.org/reflectivematerials.aspx#:~:text=The%20Environmental%20Protection%20Agency%20%28EPA%29%20has%20actively%20promoted,has%20announced%20reflective%20roof%20rules%20for%20government-financed%20buildings](https://www.asla.org/reflectivematerials.aspx#:%7E:text=The%20Environmental%20Protection%20Agency%20%28EPA%29%20has%20actively%20promoted,has%20announced%20reflective%20roof%20rules%20for%20government-financed%20buildings).

https://www.adaptationclearinghouse.org/resources/city-of-philadelphia-cool-roof-law-and-building-code.html

Comment: A link or two would make this answer even better.

Comment: what are some heat reflecting materials used (apart from light colors)

Comment: I search and put the link from state of California on the aproved roofing materials. But Basically most of  US has adopted LEED GREEN bulding code. where you earn rewards (scoring points) for energy-conserving buildings. Be it triple glazing, insulation, gray water recycling, color, and material use, taking advantage of sun exposure and seasonal angle of sun. It is a 2 term course in civil engineering.

Comment: @user29722, I edited my answer, added a link to ' cool roofs '. Check it out.

Comment: The *cool roof* link isn't working. :-(

Comment: @Fred, I fixed the cool roof link.